# Small file / Vs Big File Transfer Speeds

Tags: performance, networking, transfer, packets

Can anyone explain to me why I am able to achieve a higher transfer speed over my network with a 1158KB file compared to a 256KB file? Basically i'm looking into packet performance and the speeds achieved with different file sizes. If I send the small file with a packet size of 4096 Bytes, I achieve a transfer speed of 196.85 KB/s, but with the larger file, using the same packet size, i achieve a transfer speed of 951.48KB/s. What is the reason for such a difference? Is it just due to the larger file spending longer on the wire and being able to 'gather speed' as it were?

Update : In response to one users question, protocol is UDP and a Local network. Two computers with gigabit NIC's connected by a gigabit switch. Measuring speed with a custom java program to measure speed in response to packet size change.

Comment: What protocol? What kind of network? Local? Wan? How do you test speed etc - update your question

Comment: If you're using UDP, does the file really arrive intact in both cases? Are you using ACKs or NACks to ensure that? Details please. Your question is about the length of a piece of string at the moment.

Comment: I'm actually am not interested on whether the files are arriving intact or not. It is literally a case of chop up a file into packets, send those packets and see how long it takes to do that, regardless of  dropped / corrupt packets, reconstruction of the file at the receiver etc.

Comment: So then you're not measuring file transmission time at all. You're probably not measuring anything except packet loss. You are probably losing a greater proportion of packets with the larger file.

Answer (score 0):

The filesystem operations (making entry in directory, and updating timestamps) are probably more significant relative to the transfer time when sending small files. You could test the theory using "netcat" and discarding the file to /dev/null.

You might mention what tools/language you are using and what your environment is so other folks can help...